# SQL 2 JOINS USING SINGLE REFERENCE TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to achieve 2 joins.  If I run the 1st join alone it pulls 4 lots of results, which is correct.  However when I add the 2nd join which queries the same reference table using the results from the select statement it pulls in additional results. Please see attached.  The squared section should not be being returned
[image]

So I removed the 2nd join to try and explain better.  See pic2.  I'm trying to get another column which looks up InvolvedInternalID against the initial reference table IRIS.Practice.idvClient.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking at your query for over 3 minutes, and it still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Why are you using a `LIKE`? Shouldn't you be using an `=`? `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LIKE` is most likely the cause of your additional data results.

Comment: Make sure of the data you want to return. You have multiple rows in table2 that match to table1. This is giving you more rows than necessary. Also, in your `JOIN`s, don't use `LIKE` that way. It's not really doing anything except adding more processing to SQL. Both of those are kind of like using `ON foo LIKE foo`, where you probably should be looking for `ON foo = foo`.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Your database is simply doing as you tell it. When you add in the second join (confusingly aliased as tb1 in a 3 table query) the database is finding matching rows that obey the predicate/truth statement in the ON part of the join

If you don't want those rows in there then one of two things must be the case:

1) The truth you specified in the ON clause is faulty; for example saying `SELECT * FROM person INNER JOIN shoes ON person.age = shoes.size` is faulty - two people with age 13 and two shoes with size 13 will produce 4 results, and shoe size has nothing to do with age anyway

2) There were rows in the table joined in that didn't apply to the results you were looking for, but you forgot to filter them out by putting some WHERE (or additional restriction in the ON) clause. Example, a table holds all historical data as well as current, and the current record is the one with a NULL in the `DeletedOn` column. If you forget to say `WHERE deletedon IS NULL` then your data will multiply as all the past rows that don't apply to your query are brought in

Don't alias tables with tbX, tbY etc.. Make the names meaningful! Not only do aliases like tbX have no relation to the original table name (so you encounter tbX, and then have to go searching the rest of the query to find where it's declared so you can say "ah, it's the addresses table") but in this case you join `idvclient` in twice, but give them unhelpful aliases like tb1, tb3 when really you should have aliased them with something that describes the relationship between them and the rest of the query tables

For example, `ParentClient` and `SubClient` or `OriginatingClient`/`HandlingClient` would be better names, if these tables are in some relationship with each other.

Whatever the purpose of joining this table in twice is, alias it in relation to the purpose. It may make what you've done wriong easier to spot, for example "oh, of course.. i'm missing a `WHERE parentclient.type = 'parent'`" (or `WHERE handlingclient.handlingdate is not null` etc..)

> The first step to wisdom is by calling things their proper names